SQL Server CDC messages sequence
I have used golden gate with oracle and trying to unwrap this scenario in debezium SQL Server connector.
I have master, detail and subdetail tables with integrity constraints and insertion occurred in the same order.
How does Debezium reads these events, randomly pick tables, or we define priority of tables?
As per documentation, it reads from CDC tables not from the logs, hence the order to pick up table is not guaranteed. Is my understanding correct?
The SQL Server capture process monitors designated databases and tables, and stores the changes into specifically created change tables that have stored procedure facades.
Similarly when deletion occurred, it perform delete operation on subdetail first then detail and then master.
How does debezium for SQL Server guarantee the sequence of events in both cases?

cdc tables has order column though; see command_id: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Thank you @siggemannen for the response. Is this column maintains the orders between multiple tables? Still looking if debezium does maintains the sequence if so then how

i'm guessing it uses LSN for global order together with above to handle it. But i'm no expect in debezium. At least, it should be possible having those fields to sequence the events correctly, but if it works for your setup, i cannot answer

I would challenge your premise that Debezium does provide cross-table ordering of operations. Their FAQ says a topic is typically a single table and operations within a topic are ordered (but says nothing about ordering between topics).
